# Weblogic jdom NoClassDefFoundException

Tags: java, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror, jdom

I'm deploying my web application to Weblogic 10.3.6 on localhost and everything works as it should. But when i deploy it to the same version of weblogic which is runnig on a remote server, it throws this:

`JDOMException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/Parent: org/jdom/Parent`

The application is packed in a war file, and i upload the same file to both of the servers, but it works only on my local weblogic. Jdom.jar is located in WEB-ING/lib. I searched for jdom.jar in the directory where the remote weblogic is installed, and there is no other instance of it.

Comment: I hope you mean WEB-INF/lib.  One of these two statements is incorrect: all is not well when you run locally, because you do something different from the server that masks the problem, or there is a JDOM on the server that you missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly class loading conflict issue, please try configure WEB-INF\weblogic.xml

```
<container-descriptor>
                <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

[prefer-web-inf-classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html)

The  element, if set to true, will cause classes located in the WEB-INF directory of a Web application to be loaded in preference to classes loaded in the application or system classloader. The default value is false. A value specified in the console will take precedence over a value set manually

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class which is required by `org.jdom.Parent` is not found, not `org.jdom.Parent` itself. Some dependency is missing from your WEB-INF/lib folder.

If you are building this using maven, make sure that you include all the required optional library as well.

Comment: So jdom require other libraries? Im not using maven

Comment: unfortunately, i couldn't find what it depends on either. Have you tried Ted answer? If the required class is not found, it may be because of class loading conflict.