# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic

I am trying to deploy our EAR file in the dev environment server(Weblogic 10.3.6), After deployment while starting it is showing ?

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException.

I have checked that in lib folder I found  hibernate jars. More over it is working fine in my local weblogic 10.3.6 server.

Comment: You most likely have conflicting jars in your classpath. Hibernate is either there in two places or missing entirely. See similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351097/weblogic-jdom-noclassdeffoundexception/12351410#12351410 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020569/how-can-i-solve-a-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: After adding preferwebinf class in weblogic.xml, Now i got this error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z

Comment: it is because of using JPA2.0 in weblogic 10.3.6. any help to resolve this will be helpful